# Yesod and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, yesod

I don't know what file extensions to use coffeeScript in a Yesod application.  I was expecting to see documentation in the places but couldn't find it:

- xhttp://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates
- xhttps://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki
- xhttps://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Cookbook

i found the source code here https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/shakespeare-js/Text/Coffee.hs

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Overriding-widgetFile

You can modify the behavior of widgetFile in the scaffolding by changing the widgetFileSettings value in Settings.hs. As an example:

```
widgetFileSettings = def { wfsLanguages = \hset ->         defaultTemplateLanguages hset ++
[ TemplateLanguage True  "coffee"  Text.Coffee.coffeeFile   Text.Coffee.coffeeFileReload
] }
```